# LIst view in Android

Tags: android

In my sample program in 1stscreen i have one input field,based on this input i have to show a list view(which is another activity)how can i implement that.I am new to android.Here is my code.

This is after clicking button:

```
if(text1.getText().toString().equals("subbu"))
            { 
                startActivity(new Intent(Listview));
//              Toast.makeText(Sampleprojectsubbu1Activity.this,"Name:"+text1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            }
```

This is the list to be shown:Just for sample i have given some unwanted array.

```
public class Listview extends ListActivity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

    }
    static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] 
            {
                   "XXXXX","YYYYYY"

            };

}
```

Comment: Try to use - `startActivity(new Intent(this, ListView.class));` This will starts your `ListView` activity. And, also don't forget to add this activity to your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Try to search in google first. And, after ask the question here. Just refer the @Paresh Mayani edited answer. It will very useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Listview));
```

Correct way to start Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentClassName.this, DestinationClassName.class));
```

### Update:

To understand more about Intent, check and read below articles:

1. [Android Intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)
2. [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Can u please explain to some extent how to implement this.What is that  CurrentClassName.this, DestinationClassName.class

Comment: Agree with @SpK, don't forget to add this activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Is it possible to Display a toast with some List of text one below the other?

Answer (score 1):

In main activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ListView.class);
myIntent.putExtra("variableName", variableValue);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and in ListView class:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
String varName = extras.getString("variableName");//Datatype can be any
}
```

Comment: Reading this line from question `based on this input i have to show a list view(which is another activity)how can i implement that`, I've answered this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement like this by replacing your code line

startActivity(new Intent(Listview)); with

startActivity(MainActivty.this,ListView.class);

and it is very important to add this new activity in manifest.